# Inserting values into specific elements in an array

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble figuring out why the values the user inputs aren't being inserted into the proper element in the range array.  Can someone shed some light on this?  I'm a noob.

Thanks!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int m0 = 0;
        int m1 = 0;
        int m2 = 0;
        int m3 = 0;
        int m4 = 0;
        int m5 = 0;
        int m6 = 0;
        int m7 = 0;
        int m8 = 0;
        int m9 = 0;


        Console.WriteLine("How many entries today?");

        int entries = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] array = new int[entries];



        int[] range = new int[9];

        foreach (int i in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your sales amount");
            int sales = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (sales >= 200 && sales <= 299)
            {
                range[0] = m0++;
            }
            if (sales >= 300 && sales <= 399)
            {
                range[1] = m1++;
            }
            if (sales >= 400 && sales <= 499)
            {
                range[2] = m2++;
            }
            if (sales >= 500 && sales <= 599)
            {
                range[3] = m3++;
            }
            if (sales >= 600 && sales <= 699)
            {
                range[4] = m4++;
            }
            if (sales >= 700 && sales <= 799)
            {
                range[5] = m5++;
            }
            if (sales >= 800 && sales <= 899)
            {
                range[6] = m6++;
            }
            if (sales >= 900 && sales <= 999)
            {
                range[7] = m7++;
            }
            if (sales >= 1000 && sales <= 9999)
            {
                range[8] = m8++;
            }

        }


        foreach (int i in range)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(range[i]);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

The thing is, no matter what values the user enters, the increments aren't going to the elements in the 'range' array.  I would definitely appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you repeatedly enter the sales amount `250` (so the first `if` branch would match).

Before you enter `"250"` the first time:

```
range[0] == 0
      m0 == 0
```

After the first time:

```
range[0] == 0
      m0 == 1
```

After the second time:

```
range[0] == 1
      m0 == 2
```

As you can see, assigning the value to `range[0]` works.

What might be surprising is that `range[0]` is incremented with a 'delay'. The reason for this is the semantics of the postfix-operator `++` which increments the variable `m0` by one, but returns the original value of `m0`!

What you want is:

```
range[0] = range[0] + 1;
```

or

```
range[0]++;
```

i.e. increment `range[0]` by one. `m0` is not needed.

---

There's also a problem with your second loop to display the contents of `range`. Your code uses the values in the array as indices, which is clearly wrong. Just output the values directly:

```
foreach (int i in range)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks very much.  I wasn't sure how else to express an increment, but had a feeling there was a better way.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

**Your foreach loop is malformed.** You're trying to treat the `i` variable as an index into the array, when in fact is is *the value in the array*. When you write `foreach( x in c )`, the `x` is the actual value in the collection, not an index into the collection.

It should be:

```
foreach (int i in range) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Or, alternatively (as a regular loop):

```
for( int i = 0; i < range.Length; i++ )
{
    Console.WriteLine( range[i] );
}
```

**Your second problem is that you are using the post-increment operator on a separate value in your assignment to the `range[]` array.** This doesn't behave the way you expect. Either switch to using the pre-increment (`++m0`), or get rid of the `mXX` variables altogether, and just increment the array elements:

```
if (sales >= 200 && sales <= 299) 
{ 
    range[0]++; 
} 
if (sales >= 300 && sales <= 399) 
{ 
    range[1]++; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing the variables after adding the original value to the array element.  So when you do this:
    int m0 = 0;
    range[0] = m0++;

That is semantically the same as this:

```
int m0 = 0;
range[0] = m0;  // range[0] == 0!!!
m0 = m0 + 1;
```

So change it to this:

```
range[0] = ++m0;
```

which is essentially the same as:

```
int m0 = 0;
m0 = m0 + 1;
range[0] = m0;  // range[0] == 1
```

Do this for all your array elements and variables, and you should be fine.

HTH!